# Update a Listview label / textbox in asp.net without refreshing

Tags: asp.net, listview

How can I Update a Listview label / textbox in asp.net without refreshing the page? Please help

Comment: You can use jquery this is the best option for your problem. also can you please share your relevant code so we can review the code and share you best example.

Comment: Well you can say update a single row in a listview with client side code - but as always, it really comes down to where, where and what event and process you looking to write that will require to to trigger the update in the listview, and do so without a post back. Often, a save the day, and crutch is to continue to use code behind, and consider wrapping the listview in a update panel . while this is a bit of a cheat - it can often be of great use. but, we need the context here. Update one row? Update the whole listview? There are too many open questions here to start posting some examples